# Rename "homophone" in "homophones"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[homophone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophone) should be probably renamed [homophones](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homophones), to be consistent with the other used tags.