# Proposal to rename 'sociolinguistic' tag to 'sociolinguistics'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

[sociolinguistic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociolinguistic) should be renamed to [sociolinguistics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociolinguistics), to be consistent with general styling of the word and the related tags [linguistics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) and [psycholinguistics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psycholinguistics).

A similar request to [rename homophone to homophones](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/rename-homophone-in-homophones) is [status-completed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) (and also closed, but don't look at that).

Comment: Is there a link to the tag voting place for those synonyms?

Comment: @Mitch what's one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all done now, renamed and merged.